# iTextSharp: Convert PdfObject to PdfStream

Tags: pdf, fonts, stream, itext

I am attempting to pull some font streams out of a pdf file (legality is not an issue, as my company has paid for the rights to display these documents in their original manner - and this requires a conversion which requires the extraction of the fonts).

Now, I had been using MUTool - but it also extracts the images in the pdf as well with no method for bypassing them and some of these contain 10s of thousands of images. So, I took to the web for answers and have come to the following solution:

I get all of the fonts into a font dictionary and then I attempt to convert them into PdfStreams (for flatedecode and then writing to files) using the following code:

```
    PdfDictionary tg = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject((PdfObject)cItem.pObj);
        PdfName type = (PdfName)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(tg.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE));
        try
        {

            int xrefIdx = ((PRIndirectReference)((PdfObject)cItem.pObj)).Number;
            PdfObject pdfObj = (PdfObject)reader.GetPdfObject(xrefIdx);
            PdfStream str = (PdfStream)(pdfObj);

            byte[] bytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)str);
        }
        catch { }
```

But, when I get to **PdfStream str = (PdfStream)(pdfObj);** I get the error below:

```
    Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary' 
    to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream'.
```

Now, I know that PdfDictionary derives from (extends) PdfObject so I am uncertain as to what I am doing incorrectly here. Someone please help - I either need advice on patching this code, or if entirely incorrect, either code to extract the stream properly or direction to a place with said code.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
My revised code is here:

```
     public static void GetStreams(PdfReader pdf)
    {
        int page_count = pdf.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 1; i <= page_count; i++)
        {
            PdfDictionary pg = pdf.GetPageN(i);
            PdfDictionary fObj = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(res.Get(PdfName.FONT));
            if (fObj != null)
            {
                foreach (PdfName name in fObj.Keys)
                {
                    PdfObject obj = fObj.Get(name);
                    if (obj.IsIndirect())
                    {
                        PdfDictionary tg = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj);
                        PdfName type = (PdfName)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(tg.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE));

                        int xrefIdx = ((PRIndirectReference)obj).Number;
                        PdfObject pdfObj = pdf.GetPdfObject(xrefIdx);
                        if (pdfObj == null && pdfObj.IsStream())
                        {
                            PdfStream str = (PdfStream)(pdfObj);
                            byte[] bytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I am still receiving the same error - so I am assuming that this is an incorrect method of retrieving font streams. The same document has had fonts extracted using muTool successfully - so I know the problem is me and not the pdf.

Comment: Well, your code does give no hint whether or not the object you inspect indeed is a stream or not. please expound.

Comment: Apparently I'm not getting the stream object (just the dictionary) and I've yet to find a good answer as to how to properly grab the font streams.

Comment: Have you yet done some debugging and determined the actual class of pdfObj? And have you yet followed up to Bruno's hint and removed the cast to PdfStream in favour of a cast to PRStream? Your posted code first casts to PdfStream and then to PRStream...

Comment: Yes, the change from casting to PdfStream to casting to PRStream is on Bruno's suggestion. I've also used the code example (sorta) that he suggested to extract the stream. Now when I attempt to use PdfReader.FlateDecode() I get an error 'Buffer cannot be null', any ideas?

Comment: The buffer cannot be null error has been corrected - my error of course. I used PRStream.GetBytes() instead of PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(PRStream) and of course my byte[] was empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two things wrong in your code:

1. You cast an object to a stream without performing this check: `if (pdfObj == null && pdfObj.isStream()) { // cast to stream }` As you get the error message that you're trying to cast a dictionary to a stream, I'm 99% sure that the second part of the check will return `false` whereas `pdfObj.isDictionary()` probably returns `true`.
2. You try extracting a stream from `PdfReader` and you're trying to cast that object to a `PdfStream` instead of to a `PRStream`. `PdfStream` is the object we use to create PDFs, `PRStream` is the object used when we inspect PDFs using `PdfReader`.

You should fix this problem first.

Now for your general question. If you read ISO-32000-1, you'll discover that a font is defined using a font dictionary. If the font is embedded (fully or partly), the font dictionary will refer to a stream. This stream can contain the full font information, but most of the times, you'll only get a subset of the glyphs (because that's best practice when creating a PDF).

Take a look at the example [ListFontFiles](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=287) from my book ["iText in Action"](http://itextpdf.com/book) to get a first impression of how fonts are organized inside a PDF. You'll need to combine this example with ISO-32000-1 to find more info about the difference between `FONTFILE`, `FONTFILE2` and `FONTFILE3`.

I've also written an example that replaces an unembedded font with a font file: [EmbedFontPostFacto](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=288). This example serves as an introduction to explain how difficult font replacement is.

Please go to http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH16 if you need the C# version of the book samples.

Comment: Can't get more definitive than that! Thank you kindly sir. As to the limited glyph set, we are simply trying to display the PDF as presented (albeit in HTML) so we only need the characters presented. I very much appreciate your assistance in this!

Comment: In your opinion then, what would be the best approach to extracting a font stream from a pdf?

Comment: I added a comment on your second comment, and only then I saw your first comment. There is no simple answer to your question. The mapping of characters could be completely different. What is stored inside a PDF as the character 'a' could correspond with the glyph 'b'. You'll need to study ISO-32000-1 very closely to achieve what you want, and one outcome (the most probably outcome) could be: we can't extract a font from a PDF that can be used in HTML. If you prefer a metaphor, your question sounds like "What would be the best approach to extract whole carrots from carrot soup?"

Comment: Well, I don't need the whole carrots - just the bits. I have worked through the issue (using your suggestions) and have been able to achieve my goals. Which where, if the pdf has a chunk of text 'Make your dog vote smarter' in made up font 'DogVotes' (that is embedded in the pdf (at least using only the required characters) and I want to exactly display the document as it was originally intended; then I would only need a glyph set containing 'M' 'a' 'k' 'e' ' ' 'y' 'o' 'u' 'r' 'd' 'g' 'v' 't' 's' 'm' - which is what I am now getting. I thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.