# FlateDecode PDF Decoding

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I have a result from iTextSharp which is able to be parsed via pdf reader, but I want to be able to take the binary content and parse it manually. I've tried taking the text between the tags `<</Length 256/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream`
and
`endstream`and using the .NET DeflateStream class to attempt to decompress the text which resulted in this exception:

`System.IO.InvalidDataException: Block length does not match with its complement.                                           at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.DecodeUncompressedBlock(Boolean& end_of_block)                                        at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Decode()                                                                              at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length)                                     at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)                                    at System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)                                                at FlateDecodeTest.Decompress(Byte[] data)`

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

public class FlateDecodeTest
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        string s = @"xœuÁN!E÷|Å...";

        byte[] b = Decompress(GetBytes(s));

        Console.WriteLine(GetString(b));
    }

    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data.Length);
        byte[] decompressedArray = null;
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream compressStream = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    using (DeflateStream deflateStream = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        deflateStream.CopyTo(decompressedStream);
                    }
                }
                decompressedArray = decompressedStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }

        return decompressedArray;
    }

    static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"taking the text between the tags `<</Length 256/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream` and `endstream`"* - that is not text between there, its binary data. If you took the data from there as text, you most likely already damaged it. If by pure luck such damage did not occur, your `GetBytes` method tries to garble the data completely. Use the exact bytes from the stream content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `DeflateStream` class. If you are interested in the content stream of a page (let's say of page 1), you can use this method:

```
byte[] streamBytes = reader.GetPageContent(1);
```

Where `reader` is an instance of the `PdfReader` class. Of course, this isn't sufficient if the page has Form XObjects in its resources dictionary. In that case, you'll have to use the `PRStream` object. For instance: if a Form XObject (or any other stream object) has object number 23, than you get the `PRStream` object like this:

```
PRStream str = (PRStream)reader.GetPdfObject(23);
byte[] bytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(str);
```

As opposed to the `GetStreamBytesRaw()` method which gives you the raw, compressed bytes, the `GetStreamBytes()` method will decompress the stream. See [iTextSharp: Convert PdfObject to PdfStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343922/itextsharp-convert-pdfobject-to-pdfstream)

If you don't know the number of the object you want to examine, you can walk through the PDF object tree and for instance use the `GetAsStream()` method of a `PdfDictionary`, a `PdfArray`, and so on.